# How could a goblin ingest explosives and run, without the explosives getting into the digestive tract?

Tags: biology, creature-design, xenobiology

I am currently trying to design a kamikaze goblin. This goblin would drink explosives and have some sort of storage area within their abdominal regions. How would this goblin be able to have these explosives not go to their digestive tract, and how would they not detonate the explosives while running towards an enemy? This goblin is roughly humanoid and about four feet tall.

Comment: If it is a once-in-a-lifetime end-of-the-line kamikaze mission for the goblin why does it matter if ingested explosives go into the digestive tract?  Given their name, one would presume goblins to have capacious stomachs.

Comment: How is any liquid you drink not ending up in your lungs?

Comment: This is a reusable kamikaze goblin (to be explained later)

Comment: We all have a _storage area_ within our abdominal regions: it is called the _stomach_. And I seem to remeber reading in the news that some people actually use it as a storage area to carry cargo across borders while limiting the interactions with customs officers.

Comment: _Reusable_ kamikaze? You may want to revisit the terminology.

Comment: I bet it is reusable because it is actually a troll, not a goblin.  Trolls regenerate.

Comment: They need to be standard goblins? Or could you say they developed an accesory stomach from when they ate mostly too hard food and learned to ruminate it (like cows)? Or could they have an internal bag they can fill with air from when they were amphibious and now use for the explosives?

Comment: How much explosive? What yield do you want it to have against the enemy? What do you want it's kill radius to be? Is this a battlefield weapon or an assassination weapon?  ...and then how can you accomplish the same yield and delivery more easily than by raising nurseries full of goblins?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to make sure that the title accurately and succintly summarizes the question, without references to other questions that might already have been posted or might be posted in the future. IMO the original title of this question didn't, so I gave it a new one that I feel does. By all means feel free to [edit] further.

Answer (score 12):

I feel I should point out the utter pointlessness of this idea.

Are you familiar with the expression [Heath-Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Heath_Robinson) ?  This is the military equivalent.

Humans developed a simple method of carry objects of all kinds, including explosives - solid or liquid, without the need to swallow them : *containers*.

Is there some bizarre reason your goblin can't carry a bag or pouch or bottle ?

There's no benefit to carrying it in your body, except it's hidden, but, surprise, containers can be hidden.

And containers can be easily dropped, thrown or dismantled if need be and easily set to explode using any number of fuses, from the primitive to the ludicrously complex.

Looking at your question in this light :

> I am currently trying to design a kamikaze goblin.

No problem with a kamikaze goblin carrying a container that swallowing one will avoid.

And if you're thinking of it being hidden, all this means is that the first time one of these k-goblins explodes, *all* goblins will immediately be targeted and the purpose of hiding explosives by swallowing is lost.

> This goblin would drink explosives and have some sort of storage area within their abdominal regions.

Called a stomach in humans.  Can't see a reason it can't be called that by goblins. :-)

You can have more than one stomach if you insist on this, but it doesn't make it any better as an idea.

You might consider a kangaroo-like "pouch", but what difference ultimately is there from just having a back or satchel or strapping things to the outside of the body ?

> How would this goblin be able to have these explosives not go to their digestive tract

As someone pointed out, this is not really an issue in a *kamikaze* goblin. :-)

But note that humans, those ingenious all-purpose crazies, actually do swallow stuff to hide it and, courtesy of certain design features of the human digestive tract and the ability to wrap objects in plastic, cow gut or a variety of other materials, they will happily survive the trip through aforementioned digestive tract none the worse for wear, so to speak.

( Think drug trafficking. )

And the trick is ancient.  We've been hiding stuff from searches by swallowing for centuries.  For all I know it predates written history.

And, without being too explicit because I've just eaten, we have been known to hide things in other orifices.

But unless you've absolutely no other alternative, doing such a thing is basically not useful.  These methods have never been favored by suicide bombers over the more basic, but extremely practical, external carry method.

> , and how would they not detonate the explosives while running towards an enemy ?

... In a hail of fire which will ensure they're not going to reach any target, because pretty quickly word will spread that kamikaze goblins are active and it's shoot-on-sight time everywhere for *any* goblin.

If they had it in an external container they could throw it when they were close enough, starting the fuse when they want to.

But inside their bodies ???  If they're wounded approaching the enemy all they can do is die unless they could throw their stomachs (a rather revolving possibility which I suspect neither novel not video need explore).

This is so counterproductive from a military standpoint.

Strapping explosives *outside* your body : it works for humans, it will work for goblins.

Why make it complicated ?

> This goblin is roughly humanoid and about four feet tall.

Not after it's shot to pieces by paranoid guards, it's not. :-)

Comment: They could vomit when distressed. Man, that would make people loathe the blighters.

Comment: `Is there some bizarre reason your goblin can't carry a bag or pouch or bottle ?` He could be travelling to the past to kill/save John Connor

Comment: In addition: I presume your goblins are mostly water like humans. Water is great at absorbing showckwaves and slowing projectiles. Bullets shot into water stop after just a few meters. You may have heard of the stories of one soldier jumping onto a grenade to save his buddies. His mostly-water body absorbs most of the explosion energy and shrapnel, leaving his friends unharmed. Your Goblin would be using most of the explosive to explode himself, and little of the explosive energy would be left over for others. Whatever bomb you put in him will be much less effective than if it was outside.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine a rumiant-ish goblin.

This would have three stomachs: Two for storage, one for digesting.

The two storaging stomachs would only be connected to the mouth. There, the goblin stores excedent of food and regurgitates the food and re-eats it, moving it to the digesting stomach.

What our kamikazee goblin does is drinking two different substances that when mixed become inestable and explode. He stores one in each storaging stomach.

When he wants to explode, he simply have to regurgitate both substances.

Answer (score 1):

What about a [Throat Pouch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gular_skin) much like those found on a pelican or orangutan. Instead of risking the explosives in a rather active digestive track and needing a specific breed of goblin you could just as easily give all goblin's throat pouches which they can then use to hide the explosives and if they have to set it off with their tongue or remove the device entirely by a slight regurgitation.